# Portable dingbats with C#

Tags: c#, unicode

I am writing a C# application in which I have to show a tick mark. To my dismay, the type of fonts that all users have in their computers, such as Arial or Times New Roman, do not properly show the Dingbats portion of the Unicode character set, which includes the check mark U+2713 that I was aiming for.

My solution has been to use Wingdings, which contains the check mark (0xFC) character. However, I am a little worried that some people may not have that font in their systems.

So my question is the following: **Is there a (somewhat) universal way to show Dingbats and other Unicode characters in C#?** In particular, I am looking for a combination of a font name that pretty much everyone should have in their computers, and a short code snippet showing the proper way to make the U+2713 code appear on the screen with that font.

Thanks

Comment: I think if you're staying within windows platform U+2713, you can be pretty sure Windgdings will be there. However I've no idea how would it behave when compiled with mono on unix for example.

Comment: I'm aiming for Windows, Mono would just be the icing on the cake. Unfortunately, Windings has the same amount of *real* Dingbats as the rest: none.

Comment: Well, Arial and Times indeed don't have a glyph for U+2713.  It isn't normally a problem, font fallback take care of substituting the font.  Like it does here: ✓, comment text is displayed with Arial in your browser.  Pretty unclear why this is not happening on your machine, if you don't see the checkmark in this comment either then you ought to ask for help at superuser.com

Comment: I can see the substituted glyph on my browser, but I am hoping for some piece of code that does exactly what the browser does -- transform U+2713 into something that shows up correctly on the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you not use a checkbox control instead of a font?

The other option is to bundle the font as part of the installer or embed it in the program.

Comment: Not really, cause I was aiming at other Dingbats too, like the X-mark U+2715. However, bundling the font might be a good solution. But we are back to square one when it comes to other unicode chars.

Comment: How about using a custom font like GNU Unifont or DejaVu, that have extensive unicode support and a large number of symbols.  By bundling and using a custom font it will keep the user experience consistent.

Comment: Seems like the second best thing to do, aside from what I was looking for originally. I tend to avoid GNU due to its viral license, but DejaVu is PD, which is nice.

Comment: @legrojan The GPL applied to Unifont should be a non-issue since you wouldn't be modifying it, distributing it without "source", or linking to your application. I think it would be a stretch for anyone to claim that GPL TTF hinting code is viral. It also appears to have an exception allowing unrestricted embedding in documents if that is needed.

Comment: @KevinThibedeau Very good point. I wasn't aware of the exception in the case of fonts. My comment was obviously too general, and more focused towards code, where it certainly can be an issue. I chose DejaVu for my purposes, but I will keep Unifont in mind for next time.

Comment: GPL doesn't have *an* exception for all fonts but exceptions can be applied in specific cases which was done with Unifont.